# Projecting triangle onto a sphere

Tags: math, geometry, trigonometry, computational-geometry, geometry-surface

I'm looking to build a spherical mesh out of equilateral triangles. I've calculated the points of the triangle and managed to create a flat mesh out of them.

I'm now stuck on how to translate these points from a flat surface onto a sphere

[image: Points on flat surface]

My goal is to achieve something similar to the result from [this video](https://youtu.be/QN39W020LqU). Where the creator does something close to what I'm trying to do by projecting points from a plane onto a sphere.

[image: Example of desired result]

I've tried looking for "projecting triangle onto a sphere" results online but I've not managed to find anything that would bring me closer to a solution.